# Retrofit network callback in Espresso

Tags: android, retrofit, android-espresso

I am using Retrofit for making network calls which uses it own threadpool for the network tasks. The problem is I have written the tests in Espresso which test the UI but I don't know how to get callback from the app in the Test code so I know when the network call has ended.

How can I get a callback for network call completion in the Espresso test?

Comment: Do you want to wait for completion? Use the IdlingResource concept from espresso.